# Why doesn't PIL load locally while running Google App Engine Python 2.7 Mac OSX?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am using Google App engine on Mac OSX 10.7.4.  When I load PIL from the commandline, everything works fine.  However, when I load it from the GAE local environment, i.e.:

> import Image

Gives me the error:

> ImportError: No module named Image

This line works fine:

> from google.appengine.api import images

So I don't believe there's a problem with my installation.  The app works fine when I deploy it to GAE.  Also, I load the PIL library in app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: lxml
  version: latest
- name: PIL
  version: latest
- name: numpy
  version: latest
```

I am also using python in /usr/bin/python, 2.7.1.  I have PIL installed using:

```
brew install pip
pip install pil
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use: `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: @mjibson Is it documeted somewhere?

Comment: @WooYek Kind of [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). The library import name is PIL from that list, then you have to read the [PIL docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) about the Image module.